# Error while requesting a transaction with CXAnswerCallAction when the app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, callkit

I have an auto answer functionality in my app. When I get an incoming call and the app is in background, after the auto answer interval (i.e. 5 secs) I create **CXAnswerCallAction** with the proper call UUID and requested a transaction. I get this error.

```
Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=6 "(null)"
```

According to the Apple documentation

> Code 6 is CXErrorCodeRequestTransactionErrorInvalidAction

It was working before but suddenly it stops working. Is there anything we can do. Any help related to the issue is really appreciated.

Comment: It was working before what?

Comment: @Marco it was working before iOS 13.2

Comment: Is there no one capable to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this is that you have to be **playing audio** before you call **CXCallController.request(:)** when your app is in the background. You can even play a silent sound for a second if you want. It doesn't have to be an audible sound.

If it doesn't work, you can try using `dispatch async` with a 0.1 second delay to call

> CXCallController.request(:)

The idea is that you need to make sure the audio engine is active when you call CXCallController.request(:)

Answer (score 0):

you can user below code to perform dispatch async

```
let answerAction: CXAnswerCallAction = CXAnswerCallAction(call: uuid)
                        let transaction: CXTransaction = CXTransaction(action: answerAction)
                        let when = DispatchTime.now()+0.1

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
                            print("answering call")
                            self.callKitCallController.request(transaction, completion: { error in
                                if (error != nil)
                                {
                                    print("did answer")
                                    answerAction.fulfill()
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    print("answer failed: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                                }
                            })
                        }
```

Comment: Does this code work when the app is in the background?

Comment: sorry to say but I tried this code and its not working for background or locked state